# fast way to migrate existing mongo cluster data to new one

Tags: mongodb, migration

Currently, I have a existing mongo3.0 cluster(using `WiredTiger` storage engine and `directoryPerDB` is true) as below settings:

```
3 x shards(rs01, rs02, rs03)
2 x mongos
3 x mongo cfg
```

All the databases/collections in the 3 shards are `disabled sharded`.
and for example, there are below databases in the 3 shards.

```
in rs01: db01, db03
in rs02: db02, db05
in rs03: db04
```

Now, I bought new hardware and want to setup a new cluster for better performance. According to the usage of all databases, I need to change the positions as below:

```
in new rs01: db02, db04
in new rs02: db01
in new rs03: db05, db03
```

All the databases data are several `TB` size(about 25TB in total.). I tried to use mongo dump/export is slow. It may take several weeks to transfer all databases to new cluster?

Although in the old cluster, all nodes config `directoryPerDB: true`, I tried to create an empty database named `db01` in new `rs02` and then insert a document in `db01.co01`, then copy the local directory `/var/lib/mongodb/db01` in old `rs01` to new `rs02`. But it doesn't work.

Is there any faster way to do this? Say, copying the local files to new cluster. If I can make the process fast, I'll announce the downtime of mongo service within 1 week and do it.

@Stennie mentioned about [Migrate a Sharded Cluster to Different Hardware](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/migrate-sharded-cluster-to-new-hardware/). However, this looks like node to node data path copy.
In my case the position of all databases are redesigned for better performance, so I cannot do a node to node file copy.

Comment: do you use Open Source version? Your backup strategy uses `mongodump`or binary backups? Is the commercial `Ops Manager` available? You do the migration to the same Linux flavour as before?

Comment: yes. I use mongo 3.0.12 on all cluster nodes with official ops manager to monitor health status. We don't have any backup strategy now :(.  and original nodes and new nodes are all Ubuntu 16.04 OS.

Comment: You definitely don't want to use `mongodump` to backup a large sharded cluster (or a sharded cluster, in general) as it will be slow to dump (all data must be read by `mongod`) and require quite a few manual steps to restore into a new cluster. Are your servers bare metal or VMs? Are they physically located in the same data centre? Typically hardware upgrades can be done in a rolling fashion to avoid downtime as per [Migrate a Sharded Cluster to Different Hardware](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/migrate-sharded-cluster-to-new-hardware/).

Comment: current mongo cluster nodes are running in VMs, and we bought a new batch of physical machines for new cluster which are all in out datacenter/LAN. I read the [Migrate a Sharded Cluster to Different Hardware](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/migrate-sharded-cluster-to-new-hardware/) if I don't want to stop current cluster, and change the databases position in new cluster, seems not mentions about this topic

Comment: if I add the new cluster replica set into current cluster as (rs04, rs05, rs06). and use `db.runCommand( { movePrimary: db01, to: rs05 } )`, is it work? and users can still read/write while the command running ?

Comment: so sad ... `mongos> db.runCommand( { movePrimary: "BackFile", to: "rsRaw" } )
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "clone failed" }`