# how to add shard into current cluster without sharing any chunks

Tags: mongodb, sharding

my current cluster `sh.status()` is as below:

```
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "rsDev",  "host" : "rsDev/10.60.90.224:27003,10.60.90.224:27004" }
    {  "_id" : "rsRaw",  "host" : "rsRaw/10.60.90.224:27001,10.60.90.224:27002" }
  active mongoses:
    "3.0.14" : 1
  balancer:
    Currently enabled:  yes
    Currently running:  no
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "mike",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "rsDev" }
        mike.PDiff
            shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
            unique: false
            balancing: true
            chunks:
                rsDev   23
                rsRaw   22
            too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print
```

Now I want to add a new shard into this cluster by

```
db.runCommand({addShard: "rsPro/10.60.90.224:27005", maxSize:1})
```

After google about `maxSize`, it is a soft limit for balancer.
If I add the new shard `rsPro` using above command, it start to balance all chunks.
If I don't stop the balancer, is there any way to prevent any chunk moving to the new shard `rsPro` ?

Comment: What is your goal as far as adding a new shard but not having it accept chunk migrations? Stopping the balancer is the appropriate way to prevent migrations.

Comment: @Stennie, I am trying to [migrate data to new bought machines](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160570/fast-way-to-migrate-existing-mongo-cluster-data-to-new-one), If I add a new shard into current cluster and then use `movePrimary` to move database to new shard. Cause my boss hope we can keep service alive and also data still can keep inserting when migration.

Comment: Migrating to new hardware without downtime is the [Migrate a Sharded Cluster to Different Hardware](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/migrate-sharded-cluster-to-new-hardware/) procedure I mentioned on the related question ;-). I'll comment on the earlier question (since it has more details) to hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 0):

There is other solution, if you want to migrate you data to new machine "on-the-fly" and have only short interruption when you transfer your clients to use that new machine.  [With this you can replicate data to new location](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector)

If you want to add new shard to cluster and still keep balancer running... you can always use TAGs.. Tag your current shards and define that $MinKey - $MaxKey chunk area belongs to that TAG. [Check here what I'm talking about](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/tag-aware-sharding/)